# Hide Flash Object unless Link to It Is Clicked

Tags: html, anchor, dreamweaver, flv, streaming-flv-video

I am designing a site for my US History class and cannot seem to find any way to hide the flash object unless the link is clicked as show below.

[image: Here the Video Flash Object is Shown, but I want it to be Hidden until the Operation Satelite Link is clicked.]

Here is the code.

```
<h1><a href="#play_video">Operation Starlite</a></h1>

  <object name="play_video" classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" width="662" height="531" id="FLVPlayer">
    <param name="movie" value="FLVPlayer_Progressive.swf" />
    <param name="quality" value="high" />
    <param name="wmode" value="opaque" />
    <param name="scale" value="noscale" />
    <param name="salign" value="lt" />
    <param name="FlashVars"    value="&amp;MM_ComponentVersion=1&amp;skinName=Halo_Skin_3&amp;streamName=operation_starlite&amp;autoPlay=false&amp;autoRewind=false" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the Link to a Button and Put it in a AP Div Tag

Place the Video into a and AP Div Tag.

In Dreamweaver, hide the the AP Div Tag containing the Video. Add the onClick Behavior to the button ap div and set the button ap to (hide) and the Video ap to (show).